# Should my field be volatile when initializing on a background thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

On application startup, I am instantiating a class on a background thread, then assigning it to a variable.  I later access that variable from my main thread.  This variable is only assigned once.

My understanding is that I don't need to use the volatile keyword here, because the reference could not be cached until it is first accessed in the UI thread. Am I correct in my thinking, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I correct?

Yes. Caching is only an issue when one thread repeatedly reads a variable (written to from another thread).

And because assigning to a reference is atomic you're safe.